# Express JS cors middleware unable to store cookies on browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I want the react application to be able to store cookies in the cookie storage of browser.

I am required to send withCredentials: true in headers in axios.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
export const login = (email, password) => {
  return axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://api.*****.**/login",
    data: {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    },
  });
};
```

On the backend I am using ExpressJS cors middleware

```
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

On making login request from react using axios, in response I am getting error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.*****.**/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: Did you try to add an origin on server side? Here´s the doc [reference](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options).

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto origin it takes default as "*"

Comment: Yes, but try to set explicit `origin: 'http://localhost:3000'` to see if you keep getting it. It´s a start.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto tried that already before coming to stackoverflow to ask

Comment: You need to add ```origin: "http://localhost:3000"``` in corsOption. Then restart the server also.

Answer (score -1):

From `res.cookie('name', 'tobi', { domain: '.example.com', path: '/admin', secure: true })` remove domain in option